# How to properly annotate an Sqlalchemy return query object from different fields of various tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, annotations, python-typing

Say for instance I have an sqlalchemy query that selects like 15 fields from across 2 to 3 tables

For context consider a table `People` that we are querying

```
result = (session.execute(select(People).filter(People.id==5))).all()
```

So if we want to type the variable `result` we would probably say it has the type
`List[Tuple[People]]`

But how do we type something of this nature

```
filters=['some_filters']
result = (session.execute(
            select(
                Person.user_id,
                Person.lastname,
                Customer.house_id,
                Customer.house_name,
                Customer.streetname)
            .filter(*filters)
                ).all()
```

Note: For the sake of keeping this short i reduced the number of items in the select statement, just assume you had like 13 more items to select from various tables, how would that be best typed or annotated

Comment: This is too difficult for python typing system, I'm almost sure you cannot do it natively. You could (although I won't recommend as long as there is no extreme need in such type strictness) write a `mypy` plugin to process [PEP-593 `Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated), producing new type with corresponding fields.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here. Why wouldn't you just use `List[Tuple[int, str, int, str, str]]` to denote the types in the tuple?

Comment: @ColtonMcCormack if we had like 13 more fields of various types like that, would you still think it would be a good idea to still list them all like that, i mean wont it look kinda messy, its just my opinion actually, I'll welcome any suggestion on how to approach it